# Highlight the "Home" / "Blog" button while on main page

Tags: menus

I have been trying desesperately and in vain to highlight the button I have for "Blog" whenever I am in the the main page (I had created a custom link with my homepage)...it is really driving nuts!

The only time I have been able to highlight it was when I used the ".menu-item-has-children", but then it stays highlighted even when I enter other pages or menus (e.g.: "About" or "Archives").

Is there any way to solve this using just any CSS command or perhaps a conditional? I must say I am totally a zero with *html* and would like to avoid to use it (if possible, of course).

Many thanks in advance,
Andreas

Comment: Same your site with me so I can help you

Comment: http://loadthepistol.com/

Comment: Which one is your blog page, archives/ ?

Comment: No...the "Blog" itself. I mean, it will just redirect to the main page, where you have all the posts.

Comment: I saw it lol sorry

Comment: No worries...:D Before it was a page, not it is a linc, but this highlight did not work out in any of the cases.

Comment: Code edited. Try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress marks the currently displayed page in the menu with CSS classes `.current-menu-item`, `.current-menu-parent`, `.current-menu-ancestor`. Add the required styles to highlight items using these classes.

Sample Menu:

```
* Blog
  * First Category
  * Second Category
* About
* Contact
```

When you open **blog** page, the corresponding menu item ("**Blog**") has a class `.current-menu-item`. Similarly, when you open a **contact** page, the corresponding menu item will have a class `.current-menu-item`.

if you go to the page **second category**, the menu item "**Second Category**" will have class `.current-menu-item` and "**Blog**" item will have class `.current-menu-parent`.

---

#### UPDATE (Highlight similar to hover)

To highlight "**Blog**" on your site when you are on the home page or one of the categories ("Music & Party", "Travel & Culture", etc.) add to styles:

```
.home #menu-item-1258 > a span, 
#menu-main > .current-menu-item > a span, 
#menu-main > .current-menu-parent > a span, 
#menu-main ul .current-menu-item, 
#menu-main ul .current-menu-parent { 
   background-color: #37cadd; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks nmr, that was also very helpful! And by the way, is there a way to change the form of this highlighted menu? I would like it be exactly as the hover, which looks much cooler (like this rectangle with rounded corners).

Comment: @Andreas Yes, I updated the answer.

Comment: Hey nmr, it is not working...it is still showing the "big squares" when a page/menu is highlighted.

Comment: Did you replace `.current-menu-item, .current-menu-parent` to `.current-menu-item > a span, .current-menu-parent > a span` and remove lines `.home #menu-item-1258, .current-menu-item {`, `.current-menu-item {`? I still see the old styles in the page source (lines 840, 871, 877). @Andreas

Comment: Yes, but now it only works when I am inside the sub-categories ("Life & Health", etc). Because when I open the other tabs (e.g.: "About"), it is still showing the square. Plus, the main page is showing the square in the word "Blog" as well...

Comment: Is the current version at the address loadthepistol.com? @Andreas

Comment: Yes...and when I used your suggestion before, it would only change (the square to the nice rectangle) in the subcategories, for instance "http://loadthepistol.com/category/blog/life/"

Comment: Something is wrong with menu item "Blog", it is not marked as active when you open the page it leads to. 
These changes `.home #menu-item-1258 > a span, #menu-main > .current-menu-item > a span, #menu-main .current-menu-parent > a span, #menu-main ul .current-menu-item > a span, #menu-main ul .current-menu-parent > a span { background-color: #37cadd; }`  in styles make the first menu level similar to hover effect, items in others menu levels will be rectangular. [That's how it looks](https://postimg.cc/gallery/x1r0m7aw/)  after changes.   @Andreas

Comment: Hey nmr, I have just added the code to the other tabs (for instance "About Me") ".current-menu-item > a span,  #menu-main ul .current-menu-item > a span { background-color: #37cadd; }", and now it works great! Thanks a lot man, you have made my day.

Comment: Sry, I noticed that I made copy-paste error. After `#menu-main ul .current-menu-item` and `#menu-main ul .current-menu-parent` should not be `> a span`, otherwise 2nd menu level items will have white border.  You don't need the old line in styles `.current-menu-item > a span,  #menu-main ul .current-menu-item > a span { background-color: #37cadd; }`, this line is also responsible for the white border. @Andreas

Comment: In the previous comment I meant what [screen_1](https://postimg.cc/image/tcm5p56t3/) presents (open page `Life & Health`) , and [screen_2](https://postimg.cc/image/fixt03lxj/) is what it should look like in my opinion. I placed the updated styles in the answer. @Andreas

Comment: Yes of course, you are right. Just one extra thing: but then when inside any post, only the submenu (e.g.: Life & Health) is highlighted, not the main menu "Blog". Any more code lines you can add? :)

Comment: You use custom link as "Blod" item, try change it to static blog page ([instruction](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page#Creating_a_Static_Front_Page)).
Create empty page (set only title "Blog"), set it as **Posts page** in "**Settings** -> **Readings**" and add to menu **instead of** custom link.
Now, "blog" menu item should have a class `current_page_parent` when you open  any category or post (post_type = `post`).
Add background color for this class: `#menu-main .current_page_parent > a span { background-color: #37cadd; }`.
Should work. @Andreas

Answer (score 0):

You have to play with this CSS selector. I don't really know what do you mean by highlight, it may be a background in which case:

```
.home #menu-item-1258, .current-menu-item {
    background: blue;
}
```

If you want to elaborate, what do you mean by highlight, I can help you in case it's nothing crazy, or you can learn a bit of CSS and play with it.

In case you don't know how to add CSS, [check this out](https://en.support.wordpress.com/custom-design/editing-css/).

Comment: That works but when I change to another tab (e.g.: "About"), it stays highlighted (by that I mean with a background color)...

What I want is that it works like that "About" page, for instance: when you are inside it, it is highlighted; otherwise, it isn't.

Comment: I just changed the code, use that new one.

Comment: (By the way, is there a way to make the form of the background color - which is now like a square - the same as the one of the hover, which is like a rectangule with rounded corners?)

Comment: you can mark the answer as correct if it helps. My code example is focusing the li element, the hover thing is focusing the a, so change it to: .home #menu-item-1258 a, .current-menu-item a, it should work